# remove everything exept for .git directory and .gitignore on linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, sh, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I'm trying to delete every thing in a folder using the linux commandline except for the `.git` directory and the `.gitignore` file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /git/
# remove old files
find . ! -name '.gitignore' ! -path '.git' ! -path '.git/*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It kind of works, it deletes every thing, except for the `.gitignore` file. So what do I have to change to keep the `.git` directory (with all it's files and folders!) too?

Note: The user who will execute the script has sudo privileges

Btw. when I run it with `sudo sh cleanup.sh` the console outputs:

```
rm: cannot remove directory: ‘.’
find: `./.git': No such file or directory
find: `./foo': No such file or directory
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there an actual goal here beyond this?

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com, it's not a programming question.

Comment: @wawa take a look at my answer, simulate first and let me know how it goes. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run this:

```
find -mindepth 1 -depth -print0 | grep -vEzZ '(\.git(/|$)|/\.gitignore$)' | xargs -0 rm -rvf
```

But simulate first what it would do:

```
find -mindepth 1 -depth -print0 | grep -vEzZ '(\.git(/|$)|/\.gitignore$)' | xargs -0 echo rm -rvf
```

Explanation:

`-mindepth 1` : it will  exclude current directory

`-depth` : it will list files before folders

`print0` : it will separate each records with a null character, handy if you file name contains spaces

Comment: If I run `find -print0 | grep -vEzZ '(\.git|\.gitignore/)'` it outputs `1:.7:./foo8:./foo/bar.txt9:./foo/bar10:./foo/bar/baz.txt11:./bar.txt`. I see two problems then: first of all the current directory `1:.` will be deleted. Second the `-r` will delete `./foo/bar/` while it will try to delete it later again. That can be fixed by removing the `r` option in the delete command, but I don't know how to exclude the current directory. Another question is, why is there a `/` after .gitignore? shouldn't it be after the .git, since that's a directory?

Comment: you didn't pipe to `xargs -0 echo rm -rvf`, it won't delete just print rm -rvf <files>

Comment: and you're right WRT to current directory, so you can use `find -mindepth 1`, I will edit the answer

Comment: @wawa I addressed the two issues you mentioned.

Comment: This will not remove files like `test.git`. Incidentally, the `.gitignore` file is removed by `grep` because it matches `\,git`, _and it doesn't even match `.gitignore/` that you wrongly specified._

Comment: I am using `-v` for grep. but you're right,  I messed up, `\.git` is extension and `.gitignore` is a folder, fortunately it worked because `\.git` will also cover `\.gitnore/`

Comment: `.git` is a folder and `.gitignore` is a file. This is specified in OP.

Comment: yeah, I told the way I got it mixed up. fixed now. but `\.git` indeed matches `\.gitignore`. Thanks

Comment: @Tiago your current solution `'(\.git/|\.gitignore)'` isn't realy working, since it seams to delete the `.git` folder. However it keeps the `.gitignore` file at least.

Comment: can you run with `xargs -0 echo rm -vr` and show me the output? can be a pastebin

Comment: if I don't put a `/` after `\.git` in `'(\.git/|\.gitignore)'` it works. gut as I understood this will mach anything starting with `.git` which isn't a problem in this case, but could become on in the future.

Comment: But it's fixed with `(/|$)` if it was a problem :) can you give it a try?

Comment: This still wouldn't delete a file named `test.git`, so no, it doesn't really work. It only _seems_ to work.

Comment: OP didn't ask for 'file.git' to not be excluded. the `.git` is for directories only. `.gitignore` is for the file.

Comment: Read the question again (which actually makes sense with a little knowledge of git): _Hi I'm trying to delete every thing in a folder using the linux commandline except for the `.git` directory and the `.gitignore` file._ **delete everything** ... **except for the** ***`git` directory*** and the ***`.gitignore` file***. Where did you invent your _`.git` is for directories only. `.gitignore` is for extensions_???

Comment: `.git` directory, therefore `test.git` even if it was a directory should be excluded. WRT extensions I edited my comment few seconds after I posted it.  I think you've read the old version.

Comment: @wawa: can you please clarify: should a file/directory named `test.git` be removed?

Comment: By the way, a file named `lol.gitignore` will not be removed. `:D`.

Comment: Again `.gitignore` file not extension :)

Comment: Fair enough,  `.gitignore` issue is sorted.  Once the question is clarified I will expect you to undo your downvote :P

Comment: Hi @gniourf_gniourf and @Tiago sorry that I only answer now. Actually I'm trying to delete every thing exept for the `.git` folder and the `.gitignore` file (not extension ;)) in that directory. If there's an folder or file called `test.git` it should be removed too and also if there's a `.git` folder or `.gitignore` file in a subfolder (like vendor or something), that should be deleted. For now it's not an issue for me, since that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much point using `find` here since you only want to keep the top-level `.git` directory and `.gitignore` file (if I understand the question correctly).

Note that `rm -rf` is a recursive delete, so you don't need to walk the directory tree to do the deletes. Since `find` may well choose to execute `rm -rf ./some_directory` while it is still scanning the contents of `some_directory`, doing the recursive delete during the `find` is likely to cause you problems (such as find suddenly not being able to find files it thought it knew about).

The `-path` predicate's argument is used to match *the entire path*, starting with the root argument (`.` in your case), so `.git` won't match `./.git`.

On the whole, I'd recommend (very carefully, testing first with echo):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -fr * .!(|.|git|gitignore)
```

The second argument to `rm` is an extended glob meaning "a dot followed by anything other than: nothing or a dot or `git` or `ignore`. Excluding `.` and `..` are very important, particularly if you have root privileges.

Comment: `.` is the current directory, right? Wouldn't I need then to exclude `.git` instead of `git` and `.gitignore` instead of `gitignore`

Comment: Another option, is: `GLOBIGNORE='.git@(|ignore)'; echo rm -rf *`; this doesn't even need `shopt`ing `extglob`. Or `GLOBIGNORE='.?(.)'; shopt -s extglob; echo rm -rf !(.git|ignore)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: All good. But regardless of which technique, the recommendable is try it with echo first :) (Like many other debian/ubuntu users, I don't have to `shopt -s extglob` because the ridiculously overcomplicated tab completion scripts do it for me. But that's probably not true on vagrant.)

Answer (score 1):

`-path` refers to the full path in `find`. `.git` is not a full path, `./.git` is.

So, the below would probably work

```
find . ! -name '.gitignore' ! -path './.git' ! -path './.git/*' -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

But, it still has 2 points of recursion going over the same files (the `find` and the `rm -r`). If you want to avoid errors (especially since `find` pre-processes parts of the tree) you should really have only one

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.gitignore' ! -name '.git' -exec echo rm rf {} +
```

The `-mindepth` is needed to avoid processing the current working directory `.` as a file.

*As with [rici's option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463847/3076724), remove the `echo` to actually do the removal*